# Hacer SELECT con 20 Monstruos diferentes IDs en SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente estructura de SQL server:

```
ROW    Monstruo MobID Fecha
1      Feo      4001  14-12-2016 22:22:03
2      Horrible 4002  12-12-2016 22:22:03
3      Espanto  4003  11-12-2016 22:22:03
4      Espanto  4003  17-12-2016 22:22:03
5      Tesoreo  4004  12-12-2016 22:22:03
6      FEO      4001  11-12-2016 22:22:03
```

Necesito hacer una consulta SELECT de SQL server que capte los monstruos por MobID por fecha mas reciente OMITIENDO las fechas mas viejas y sin tomar los Mobs IDS repetidos EJEMPLO que deberia tener el resultado del SELECT

```
ROW    Monstruo MobID Fecha
1      Feo      4001  14-12-2016 22:22:03
2      Horrible 4002  12-12-2016 22:22:03
4      Espanto  4003  17-12-2016 22:22:03
5      Tesoreo  4004  12-12-2016 22:22:03
```

IMPORTANTE el registro tiene mas de 1000 registros y de los cuales son más de 5000 MobID distintos que van desde MobID 1 al 8035 con sus distintos nombres este ejemplo de arriba fue un ejemplo a escala pequeña.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes ocupar `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  [ROW],
            Monstruo,
            MobId,
            Fecha,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Monstruo ORDER BY Fecha DESC)
    FROM dbo.TuTabla 
)
SELECT [ROW],
        Monstruo,
        MobId,
        Fecha
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```